# WCF Weird Service Behavior

Tags: wcf, network-protocols, protocolexception

I'm using a wsHttpBinding service that is working perfectly since now. My WPF application (client) is connected to it and automatically receives information from the server every 15 seconds.

I've been noticing that sometimes (once in a while, some days there is no problem) my client receives the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<html>
    <head>
        <title>  </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function bredir(d,u,r,v,c){var w,h,wd,hd,bi;var b=false;var p=false;var s=[[300,250,false],[250,250,false],[240,400,false],[336,280,false],[180,150,false],[468,60,false],[234,60,false],[88,31,false],[120,90,false],[120,60,false],[120,240,false],[125,125,false],[728,90,false],[160,600,false],[120,600,false],[300,600,false],[300,125,false],[530,300,false],[190,200,false],[470,250,false],[720,300,true],[500,350,true],[550,480,true]];if(typeof(window.innerHeight)=='number'){h=window.innerHeight;w=window.innerWidth;}else if(typeof(document.body.offsetHeight)=='number'){h=document.body.offsetHeight;w=document.body.offsetWidth;}for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){bi=s[i];wd=Math.abs(w-bi[0]);hd=Math.abs(h-bi[1]);if(wd<=2&&hd<=2){b=true;p=bi[2];}}if(b||(w<100&&w!==0)||(h<100&&h!==0)){if(p&&self==parent){self.close();return;}return'/b'+'anner.php?w='+w+'&h='+h+'&d='+d+'&u='+u+'&r='+r+'&view='+v;}else{return c;}}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="window.l'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Would you have any idea on where to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Camille.

Comment: not sure why you have that html in ur payload. I would suggest see if you cant encode the xml payload.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that occasionally the service you are connecting to has a problem and is responding with an html error page. This might be a 404 Page Not Found or a 503 Service Unavailable or a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: all right.. but how may I debug this? I'm restricted to the first 1024 bytes here, and can't get more from the client (WPF) side...

Comment: Sorry for the lateness of my reply. I would probably start using something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to sniff the http requests and responses. In the response you will see a html page returned when you have a problem most likely. A tool like Fiddler is useful because it will investigate the response before it is handed to your application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to security negotiation. There is a chance that your security context is being cached - so when the session expires, the security context is not valid anymore, but it still try to pass it on. You might need to check this and that you are closing your connection everytime.

And you might end up having to implement a retry routine (your client code to catch that communication exception and when this occurs throw the current Client object away and create a new one (something like a retry). I had to do this in one of my clients.

I hope this helps.

Cheers, Wagner.

Comment: unfortunately, keeping the security session is a must to me. I won't be able to re-create the connection without loosing my authentication methods (and license selection).

Comment: You might be able to cache the ClientCredentials object and pass it back to the new Client once you recreate the connection.